django model add scheme to url field if not represented
I have a model with a URL field in my Django rest framework project. I want to ensure that a scheme (like https://) is added to the URL if it doesn't exist.
from django.db import models
class MyModel(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()

I've tried using the clean, save, clean_fields methods, but none of them seem to work.
I feel there should be a straightforward way to accomplish this, but I can't find one.
For example I want to send "google.com" in my POST request and add https:// before validating via URLField. If I change the field value in save or clean methods, it still gives me a validation error: 'Enter a valid URL'.
Any suggestions or best practices would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

I don't really get why you expect clean/save/... to add https, it could also be ftp, tel, mailto, magnet, etc.

@willeM_VanOnsem, I don't expect them to add https. I expected that i could change the raw data and added https to the sent url. but it throws a validation error before running any of my code.

What error you received from server?

@Tanveer I've edited the original question

doing it in javascript could be one solution

@folengateis I guess I have to give up URLField or change my input via javascript.

I found a solution to my own question, which overrides the to_internal_value method of URLField in the serializer, I realized that I should change the data in my serializer instead of the model.
class CustomURLField(serializers.URLField):
    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        value = super().to_internal_value(value)
        if value and not (value.startswith('http://') or 
 value.startswith('https://')):
            value = 'https://' + value
        return value

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = CustomURLField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
    fields = '__all__'

If I didn't use Django REST Framework, I guess that I would have to override the to_python method in the model field instead.

For this problem I highly recommend to make a custom save function for your model to check if there is no https:// or http:// create one for it
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.url.startswith("http://")):
            self.url = "http://" + self.url
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)


It doesn't work. It throws a validation error before running save()

do you use drf?
